# Fullcalender custom mothsNames

Tags: fullcalendar

everyone.

is there a way to add custom month names to the custom locale Fullcalendar ?
I have tried locale, but custom locale does't include. any custom days name or custom months name
I have serached alot with no. good explination.
please any help

Comment: Tag your programming language and add some code you work with actually...

Answer (score 0):

This is based on what's in the JavaScript DateTime object and what is output will depend on your browser and fullCalendar locale settings. There some options to configure exactly what is displayed, which might help you, depending on what precisely you want to change - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting